# Update Git to Latest Version (mac)

Tags: git, macos

I'm running Git version 1.6.5.1.  The binary is sitting in /usr/local/git/bin.  Is there an easy way to update to the latest version?

Comment: That depends on how you originally installed the program. Generally you should upgrade using the same method.

Comment: I used to use a source checkout; then upgrading becomes a one-liner: `cd ~/src/git && git pull && NO_FINK=1 make install`

Comment: I ended up just installing homebrew.

Comment: git clone https://github.com/git/git

Comment: Other than homebrew there is also macports. How to install git with Macports? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13889177/how-to-install-git-with-macports However both adds one dependency each, either it is homebrew or macports.

Comment: ... and there is fink project with git package with the same outcomes as Macports and homebrew.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I ended up just installing homebrew.

Comment: This is definitely the easiest way to get git if you don't care about tracking the development.

Comment: I did install by brew using `brew update && brew install git`, but when I type `git --version` it shows the apple version. How do I set the default version to the one that I've installed by brew ?

Comment: `brew install git` and then reopening the terminal session worked for me, thanks.

Answer (score 11):

From the Git README file:

> ## UPGRADING
>
> Simply download the latest Git installer, run the provided uninstall.sh script, and then install as normal.

[Download and install from Git's website](http://git-scm.com/)

Comment: The uninstall script won't do anything if you haven't installed from a Git installer in the past (if git is installed in a different directory than it expects).

Comment: See this Gist: https://gist.github.com/wjn/9252854

Once you identify where Git is installed, you should be able to modiy the `sudo rm` lines to reflect the correct directories to remove.

Answer (score 6):

the simplest way I found so far is from git official website.

http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-Installing-Git

> The other major way is to install Git via MacPorts
>   (http://www.macports.org). If you have MacPorts installed, install Git
>   via
>
> $ sudo port install git-core +svn +doc +bash_completion +gitweb

Answer (score 1):

I found the easiest option to be to download directly from Git's website:

http://git-scm.com/downloads

From there, I ran their installation package, quit and relaunched Terminal, and checked:

`git --version`

Updated!

For what it's worth, my `which git` reads:

`/usr/local/git/bin/git`

And I have in my `.bash_profile`:

`export PATH=/usr/local/git/bin:$PATH`

Comment: Yeah, this didn't work for me. It was not updated. No clue how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 0):

Check [Dan Benjamin](http://hivelogic.com/articles/compiling-git-on-snow-leopard) blog. Just change `git-1.6.4.2` for the latest version.

Comment: kindly provide a detailed answer or direct link. the link provided navigates to wrong page.