# How to install git with Macports?

Tags: git, installation, macports

Git used to work fine on my Mac OS X.  Today i found it not working:

```
$ git
-bash: git: command not found
```

I installed previously with Macports.  Now if i try again, the following happens:

```
$ sudo port install git-core
Portfile changed since last build; discarding previous state.
--->  Computing dependencies for git-core
--->  Fetching archive for git-core
--->  Attempting to fetch git-core-1.8.0.2_0+credential_osxkeychain+doc+pcre+python27.darwin_10.x86_64.tbz2 from http://packages.macports.org/git-core
--->  Attempting to fetch git-core-1.8.0.2_0+credential_osxkeychain+doc+pcre+python27.darwin_10.x86_64.tbz2 from http://mse.uk.packages.macports.org/sites/packages.macports.org/git-core
--->  Attempting to fetch git-core-1.8.0.2_0+credential_osxkeychain+doc+pcre+python27.darwin_10.x86_64.tbz2 from http://lil.fr.packages.macports.org/git-core
--->  Fetching distfiles for git-core
--->  Attempting to fetch git-1.8.0.2.tar.gz from http://ykf.ca.distfiles.macports.org/MacPorts/mpdistfiles/git-core
--->  Attempting to fetch git-manpages-1.8.0.2.tar.gz from http://ykf.ca.distfiles.macports.org/MacPorts/mpdistfiles/git-core
--->  Attempting to fetch git-htmldocs-1.8.0.2.tar.gz from http://ykf.ca.distfiles.macports.org/MacPorts/mpdistfiles/git-core
--->  Verifying checksum(s) for git-core
--->  Extracting git-core
--->  Applying patches to git-core
--->  Configuring git-core
--->  Building git-core
--->  Staging git-core into destroot
--->  Installing git-core @1.8.0.2_0+credential_osxkeychain+doc+pcre+python27
--->  Activating git-core @1.8.0.2_0+credential_osxkeychain+doc+pcre+python27
Error: org.macports.activate for port git-core returned: Image error: /opt/local/libexec/git-core/git-subtree already exists and does not belong to a registered port.  Unable to activate port git-core. Use 'port -f activate git-core' to force the activation.
Please see the log file for port git-core for details:
    /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_git-core/git-core/main.log
To report a bug, follow the instructions in the guide:
    http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets
Error: Processing of port git-core failed
21:51 foouser@barhost:~$ sudo port -f activate git-core
--->  The following versions of git-core are currently installed:
--->      git-core @1.7.7.2_0+doc+pcre+python27
--->      git-core @1.7.7.4_0+doc+pcre+python27
--->      git-core @1.7.9_0+doc+pcre+python27
--->      git-core @1.7.9.2_0+doc+pcre+python27
--->      git-core @1.7.9.2_1+credential_osxkeychain+doc+pcre+python27
--->      git-core @1.7.9.4_0+credential_osxkeychain+doc+pcre+python27
--->      git-core @1.7.10_0+credential_osxkeychain+doc+pcre+python27
--->      git-core @1.7.11.3_0+credential_osxkeychain+doc+pcre+python27
--->      git-core @1.7.11.5_0+credential_osxkeychain+doc+pcre+python27
--->      git-core @1.7.12.2_0+credential_osxkeychain+doc+pcre+python27
--->      git-core @1.8.0.1_0+credential_osxkeychain+doc+pcre+python27
--->      git-core @1.8.0.2_0+credential_osxkeychain+doc+pcre+python27
Error: port activate failed: Registry error: Please specify the full version as recorded in the port registry.
```

It still is not working.  How should i restore my beloved git?

Comment: Why don't you do what the error tells you and specifiy a full version? (and uninstall the ~10 old versions that you have installed)

Comment: How to uninstall the old versions all together?

Comment: Have a look here: http://guide.macports.org/#using.common-tasks.removeinactive

Comment: this will help you to upgrade git version: https://gist.github.com/happygiraffe/148374

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have multiple `git-core` installed on your system. You need to be more precise on which you want to **add**. Otherwise activate a specific version.

For example, you can do :

```
sudo port install git-core @1.7.11.3_0+credential_osxkeychain+doc+pcre+python27
```

to choose the version **1.7.11.3_0** with the mentioned variants.
Or the last version by doing :

```
sudo port install git-core @1.8.0.2_0+credential_osxkeychain+doc+pcre+python27
```